# Need cross instead tick in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to convert the tick mark to a cross mark, I have no knowledge of SVG, so anyone can convert the following tick animation to a cross animation?

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg>
```

I have tried my best but the tick join point doesn't splits, tick tail and head attached, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your "question" was, fundamentally, "can you do this for me?" - you had a very specific use-case that's really not going to end up being helpful to future visitors. I helped you out this time, but more generally you should look to hire a developer if you want actual work doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My thought process:

- Not really a StackOverflow-worthy question...
- But I am a sucker for SVG
- I'm gonna do it anyway.

So here you go! I've just changed the `<path />` for you.

```
d="M14.1 14.1l23.8 23.8 m0,-23.8 l-23.8,23.8"
```

Start in the top-left (at 14.1,14.1), go diagonally down-right for 23.8 units, then "pick up the pen" and move 23.8 units up before going down-left for 23.8 units.

Looks good to me!

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 14.1l23.8 23.8 m0,-23.8 l-23.8,23.8"/></svg>
```